# Expand shared memory C shmget

Tags: c, shared-memory

Is it possible to expand a shared memory allocation that was allocated using `shmget`?

I've tried searching through the `man` pages of `shmget` and `shmctl`. Neither provide a suggestion for doing so.

Comment: No. Once it's created you cannot increase its size. You have to create a new one and put a "link" to the new one in a fixed place in the old one.

Comment: @JeffHolt That's what I was doing, just wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way around it.

Comment: I think the question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423789/can-i-resize-linux-shared-memory-with-shmctl

Comment: @Landstalker It looks like that user was using C++. Wasn't sure if the same functions in C++ could be used in C.